# How to make a deep copy of an object of a generated final class using Reflection API

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I found a useful method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25338780/4440694)
but it fails to work with classes with array members e.g.

```
public class Test {
    int [] arr = new int[2];
}
```

Full code from the answer mentioned above
with my failing attempts to instantiate new array:

```
public static Object cloneObject(Object _obj) {
    try {
        // begin my changes
        Object copy = null;
        if (!_obj.getClass().isArray())
            copy = _obj.getClass().newInstance();
        else {
            int len = Array.getLength(_obj);
            Class type = _obj.getClass().getComponentType();
            // Next line fails with: Compiler(syntax) error
            // copy = (type.getClass()[])Array.newInstance(_obj.getClass(), len);
            // Next line fails with: "InstantiationException: int cannot be instantiated"
            // copy = _obj.getClass().getComponentType().newInstance();
            // how then?
        }
        // end my changes
        for (Field field : _obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(_obj) == null || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers()))
                continue;
            if (field.getType().isPrimitive() ||
                field.getType().equals(String.class) ||
                field.getType().getSuperclass().equals(Number.class) ||
                field.getType().equals(Boolean.class)
            )
                field.set(copy, field.get(_obj));
            else {
                Object child = field.get(_obj);
                if (child == _obj)
                    field.set(copy, copy);
                else
                    field.set(copy, cloneObject(field.get(_obj)));
            }
        }
        return copy;
    } catch (Exception _e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that every array type has a clone method which you can use like

```
int[] array={ 1, 2, 3 }, copy=array.clone();
```

Unfortunately, this method is not reported by Reflection, so in order to invoke it reflectively, you have to lookup `Object.clone()` and, since this base class’ method is declared `protected`, make it accessible via `setAccessible(true)` despite the fact that the array’s overriding method is `public`.

Further, this creates only a shallow copy, so in case of object arrays or multiple dimensions, you have to repeat this step recursively. But since all multi-dimensional arrays are also a subtype of `Object[]`, they can be handled uniformly:

```
if(_obj.getClass().isArray()) {
    Method cloneMethod = Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("clone");
    cloneMethod.setAccessible(true);
    copy=cloneMethod.invoke(_obj);
    if(copy instanceof Object[]) {
        Object[] array=(Object[])copy;
        for (int ix = 0; ix < array.length; ix++)
            array[ix]=cloneObject(array[ix]);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the array that is returned by the `Array.newInstance` method as you are assigning it to a variable of type `Object` (which will accept any object, and arrays are also objects)

Just do:

```
copy = Array.newInstance(type, len);
```

Comment: now it fails on line `field.set(copy, cloneObject(field.get(_obj)));` with `IllegalArgumentException: "field Test.arr has type int[], got int[][]"`

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov You asked about your changes and I answered your question. It looks like you say that part works now, so I guess it's the correct answer. If you have a new question, please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Alexey Andronov: you have to use `type` just like in this answer rather than `_obj.getClass()`, as `Array.newInstance` expects the component type. But note that this only creates a new array of the same type, not a copy.